# angular filter is date time format-er

Tags: angularjs

I have angular Filter and always show wrong time from json is '2015-04-09T16:30:00' the problem is it show time 2015-04-09 12:30 PM off 4 hour of correct time 
how can I show corect time ?

```
app.filter('formatDateAndTime', function () {
    return function (input){
        if (moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm ') === 'Invalid date')
            return ' ';
        else
            return moment.utc(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm ');
    };
});
```

Comment: Is your local timezone 4 hours different from UTC?

Comment: @DavidBalažic is  (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Comment: I don't know why it is off ?

Comment: Do you have DST in effect? What is the local time right now there?

Comment: yes it is active? right now it round  3:40 PM

Comment: There, in UTC it is 7:40 PM, 4 hours difference. As I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74875/discussion-between-david-balazic-and-user3277743).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *moment.utc(x)* call interprets the input as UTC time and then *.local()* outputs it in local timezone, which is 4 hours off.

Oops, I missed the part of the question about getting the same time. See [Ben Whitney's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29547638/822870) (use *moment(input)* instead of *moment.utc(input)*)

Comment: Solve what? What is your problem? Or goal? Reformat the date string?

Answer (score 1):

As David mentions you don't want to use UTC.

Use moment(x) instead of moment.utc(x).

So your code would be:

```
app.filter('formatDateAndTime', function () {
    return function (input){
        if (moment(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm ') === 'Invalid date')
        return ' ';
        else
            return moment(input).local().format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm ');
    };
});
```